# Old site being loaded on mobiles when on 4G connections

Tags: dns, mobile

Have deployed a new website for a client to my server a few months ago. The ip address propagated and the new site can be viewed on pc and mobile when on the wifi. When people are not on the wifi, i.e. using 4G, and hit refresh, the old site loads up.

This doesn't appear to be a local cache issue as we've cleared local cache on ios and the issue continues. Also, new devices can show the new site on wifi then the old site when the come on 4G. This suggests a caching issue with the 4G provider, but this is also affecting different providers - EE and Sky Broadband.

How can I stop the old site from being loaded / force these 4G providers to accept the new IP address of this website?

---

Note: When I talk about the device being on 4G I am referring to any mobile data connection (i.e. E, G, 3G, 4G).

Comment: Somewhat similar issue, try the suggestions: https://serverfault.com/questions/554925/domain-name-works-with-3g-connection-but-not-on-wifi

Comment: How long has the DNS (the new IP address) been propagating? It can take up to 48 hours for changes to reflect on all ISPs.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister About three months. Last month, in an effort to re-propagate, we changed the TTL of the A record. That didn't work either.